# Streaming audio from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, audio, stream

Is it possible to stream audio-file from `BlobStore` on AppEngine in general?
And if yes, what about streaming **.mp3** file from direct url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep!!
This is my implementation:

```
public class Serve extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5603629129606331547L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
        BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().serve(blobKey, res);
    }
}
```

.. and this is the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class><my-package>.Serve</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serve</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pay attention that "direct url" (getServingUrl I think you mean) exists only for images:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore

Comment: Except that this is not streaming. It's just a file download.

Comment: uhm.. @PeterKnego you are right: here is the right class for streaming https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream

Comment: Sorry, but no. Streaming means that you deliver data as needed, e.g. as user views/listens to the media. Download means that you send the data as fast as possible and client caches it. App Engine limits requests to 30s, so you can not do streaming.

Comment: @PeterKnego The only difference between streaming and downloading is how the data's consumed; clients can control that by reading data only as they need it. App Engine's execution limit applies only to code execution time, not to the time taken to upload or download data, so this solution works just fine.

Comment: @Nick - actually difference is in how data is served. In true streaming (RTSP, RTMP) client will notify server of stream consumption and server will accordingly send more/less data. So connection is all the time open and there needs to be code on server acting on client signals.

Comment: @Nick - then there is Http Live Streaming, which chunks up file in small file downloads and serves this downloads according to line quality. This could potentially be implemented on GAE as it's just a series of small file downloads: ahttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

Comment: @Nick - then there is "youtube streaming", which is one large file download, but it's progressive (starts at a position signaled by client) and it throttles download according to video datastream. This could not be implemented on GAE as it needs to execute custom code (dl throttling based on video stream speed) during stream download.

Comment: @PeterKnego Yes, you can stream over protocols other than HTTP, or by layering a protocol over HTTP. You can also stream simply by sending the client a file that it consumes as fast as it needs, which is clearly what the OP wanted, and is perfectly practical on App Engine.

Comment: Beware of bug http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3219 though... prevents "streaming" of .wav files.

Comment: Came here looking for a _streaming_ solution for App Engine, so that I could conserve outgoing traffic if a user starts listening to an mp3 but navigates away after a few seconds (perhaps they search through dozens of mp3s before they find the one they want to listen to). This solution doesn't conserve any outgoing traffic because it's not true streaming; it sends everything down at once.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is **no**:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled#streaming_responses

As others have indicated you could chunk up your data to limit the "cost" and then have your client control when to get the next chunk.

**A better solution**
Use Cloud Run instead:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-http-grpc-server-streaming